# GridView is not visible in the output

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, left-join, sqldatasource

Okay!
I am trying to merge 4 Tables which i have aliased in SelectCommand.
Problem--> The GridView is not visible in the final output
Guesswork--> I even tried without alias (Didn't work still). So i am kinda lost as where i am going wrong

Tell me if any more information that i can provide?

```
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="FirstName_HiddenField" Value="s"/>
    <div id="StudentDetails">
        <div id="StudentDetailsBanner">
            Student Details
        </div>
        <div id="StudentDetailsContent">
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"
                 ID="SqlDataSource_FirstName"
                 ConnectionString="Data Source=NIRMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KohinoorDatabaseTrial3;Integrated Security=True" 
                 SelectCommand="SELECT SD.enq_id, SD.reg_id, SD.first_name, SD.middle_name, SD.last_name, SED.enq_date, POD.name, SD.DOB, SD.contact_no1, SCD.course, SD.admission_type
                                    FROM StudentDetails AS SD
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentEnquiryDetails AS SED
                                    ON SD.enq_id = SED.enq_id
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentCourseDetails AS SCD 
                                    ON SD.enq_id = SCD.enq_id
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ParentOccupationDetails AS POD 
                                    ON SD.enq_id = POD.enq_id
                                    WHERE SD.first_name LIKE '%@FirstName%'">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FirstName_HiddenField" Name="FirstName" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView runat="server"
                ID="StudentDetailsGridView" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="StudentDetailsGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                Width="100%" 
                AllowPaging="true" 
                PageSize="10"
                CssClass="GridViewTable" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Visible="true">

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SD.enq_id" HeaderText="Enq No" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SD.reg_id" HeaderText="Reg No" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Name" Text='<%# Bind("SD.first_name") + " " + Bind("SD.middle_name") + " " + Bind("SD.last_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SED.enq_date" HeaderText="Enq Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="POD.name" HeaderText="Guardian" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SD.DOB" HeaderText="Date of Birth" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SDcontact_no1" HeaderText="Contact No" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SCD.course" HeaderText="Course" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SD.admission_type" HeaderText="Admission Type" />
                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="TableHeadingRow" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="TableRow" />
            </asp:GridView>                 
        </div>
    </div>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StudentDetailsGridView.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource_FirstName.ID;
    StudentDetailsGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Make sure your query returns results. That will tell you if the problem is with your GridView or with your query.

Comment: Yes the query is working.

Comment: Set the StudentDetailsGridView.EmptyDataText property to something like "No results found." in your markup. See info about [EmptyDataText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext(v=vs.110).aspx) property on MSDN.

Comment: Try what @mason said. See if you can get anything to show on the page.. Alternatively, you can send me a link to your project so that I can have a look, along with an extract of your data (a csv file with sample data will suffice). thanks

Comment: Thanks @mason. Yes it shows "No Result Found" . But i dont get how MS SqlServer gives  me rows and ASP.NET gives me "No result Found"? So something is wrong with the query but what ? seems perfectly normal! :/

Comment: Okay Mason's comment got me thinking and i modified my query as WHERE StudentDetails.FirstName LIKE '%s%' and removed all alias from GridView and wow i got GridView displaying <b>BUT</b> when i replaced '%s%' with '%@FirstName%' then again i am getting "No Result". So how do i frame that part of the query??

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be

```
StudentDetailsGridView.DataSource = SqlDataSource_FirstName;
```

??

in the code behind? I think that you are not binding your SqlDataSource to your gridview correctly and that's your problem...

Comment: No! it still isnt working --Changed DataSourceID to DataSource and SqlDataSource_FirstName.ID to SqlDataSource_FirstName like you said

Comment: Could you comment out your column definition and set AutoGenerateColumns=true? I wander if there is a binding issue? And you are certain that the datasource is fully populated - only double checking?

Comment: Hey Chris i changed my query as follows
"SELECT * FROM StudentDetails AS SD
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentEnquiryDetails AS SED
ON SD.enq_id = SED.enq_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentCourseDetails AS SCD 
ON SD.enq_id = SCD.enq_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ParentOccupationDetails AS POD
ON SD.enq_id = POD.enq_id
WHERE SD.first_name LIKE '@FirstName%' OR SD.middle_name LIKE '%@FirstName%' OR SD.last_name LIKE '%@FirstName%'"
Still i am not getting the GridView in the browser.
On my MS SqlServer 2008 i get 17rows matching the above criteria.
Yes i even set the AutoGenerateColumns = true

Answer (score 1):

Woah!! Got it !!

Mistake 1) **Dont use Alias in DataField property** (My Theory- DataField uses column name of final result table which is void of alias)
Mistake 2) **'%' + @FirstName + '%'** instead of %@FirstName%

So just to get the overview and let this question be helpful to others

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="FirstName_HiddenField" Value="s"/>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server"/>
    <div id="StudentDetails">
        <div id="StudentDetailsBanner">
            Student Details
        </div>
        <div id="StudentDetailsContent">
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"
                 ID="SqlDataSource_FirstName"
                 ConnectionString="Data Source=NIRMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KohinoorDatabaseTrial3;Integrated Security=True" 
                 SelectCommand="SELECT SD.enq_id, SD.reg_id, SD.first_name, SD.middle_name, SD.last_name, SED.enq_date, POD.name, SD.DOB, SD.contact_no1, SCD.course, SD.admission_type
                                    FROM StudentDetails AS SD
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentEnquiryDetails AS SED
                                    ON SD.enq_id = SED.enq_id
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentCourseDetails AS SCD 
                                    ON SD.enq_id = SCD.enq_id
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ParentOccupationDetails AS POD 
                                    ON SD.enq_id = POD.enq_id
                                    WHERE SD.first_name LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'" >
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FirstName_HiddenField"  Name="FirstName" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView runat="server"
                ID="StudentDetailsGridView" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="StudentDetailsGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                Width="100%" 
                AllowPaging="true" 
                PageSize="10"
                CssClass="GridViewTable" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Visible="true" EmptyDataText="No Result Found">

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="enq_id" HeaderText="Enq No" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="reg_id" HeaderText="Reg No" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Name" Text='<%# Bind("first_name") + " " + Bind("middle_name") + " " + Bind("last_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="enq_date" HeaderText="Enq Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Guardian" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="Date of Birth" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="contact_no1" HeaderText="Contact No" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="course" HeaderText="Course" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="admission_type" HeaderText="Admission Type" />
                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="TableHeadingRow" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="TableRow" />
            </asp:GridView>                 
        </div>

    </div>
```

Cheers guys :)